# 2 Date Ranges - How many days from one range excluding weekends overlap

Tags: sql-server, date

First - Thanks for your help.

I'm looking to create a query in SQL that provides the me the # of days from one date range that overlap another date range and excludes weekends.

Example Data:

```
Training Dates - 10/16/2014 - 10/28/2014
Fiscal Month Dates - 09/22/2014 -10/21/2014
```

Number of Days the training overlaps the Fiscal Month Excluding Weekends: 4 Should be the Answer (16th, 17th, 20th, and 21st)

Again Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Create date tables or table variables with your ranges and do the join query. Assuming SQL Server as the database, my sample solution is given below.

```
Declare @Range1Begin date = '10/16/2014',
        @Range1End   date = '10/28/2014',
        @Range2Begin date = '9/22/2014',
        @Range2End   date = '10/21/2014';

Declare @DateTable1 table (Date1 date);

Insert into @DateTable1
select dateadd(day, number, @Range1Begin)
from 
    (select distinct number from master.dbo.spt_values
     where name is null) n
where dateadd(day, number, @Range1Begin) <= @Range1End;

Declare @DateTable2 table (Date2 date);

Insert into @DateTable2
select dateadd(day, number, @Range2Begin)
from 
    (select distinct number from master.dbo.spt_values
     where name is null ) n
where dateadd(day, number, @Range2Begin) <= @Range2End;


-- Get individual dates
select dt1.Date1 as date, datename(w, dt1.date1) as weekday from @DateTable1 dt1
inner join @DateTable2 dt2
on dt1.date1 = dt2.date2
where datepart(w, dt1.date1) not in (1,7);


-- Get total days
select count(*) as TotalDays from @DateTable1 dt1
inner join @DateTable2 dt2
on dt1.date1 = dt2.date2
where datepart(w, dt1.date1) not in (1,7);
```

Without declaring table variables, following is the solution.

```
Declare @Range1Begin date = '10/16/2014',
        @Range1End   date = '10/28/2014',
        @Range2Begin date = '9/22/2014',
        @Range2End   date = '10/21/2014';

-- Get total days
select count(*) as TotalDays from (select dateadd(day, number, @Range1Begin) date1
from 
    (select distinct number from master.dbo.spt_values
     where name is null) n
where dateadd(day, number, @Range1Begin) <= @Range1End) dt1
inner join (select dateadd(day, number, @Range2Begin) date2
from 
    (select distinct number from master.dbo.spt_values
     where name is null ) n
where dateadd(day, number, @Range2Begin) <= @Range2End) dt2
on dt1.date1 = dt2.date2
where datepart(w, dt1.date1) not in (1,7);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating a date table? I don't have write access to the database just read only. The Start and end dates for each range are already in a table.

Comment: My first implementation uses table variables, not tables. You do not need write access to the database for that. I also updated the codes implementation without declaring the table variable.